# Leave him alone

Tags: expressions

> Leave him alone.

I'm wondering if this expression can be used physically (to move away, depart), as well as mentally (don't interfere his choices).

Comment: Yes, it certainly can. :-)

Comment: @ralph.r  Thanks.  By the way, do you think I can correctly summarize those two uses as **physically vs mentally?**

Comment: Hm, depends. I would say maybe "physically vs verbally", or perhaps "physically vs psychologically". But "leave him alone" by itself covers all bases, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving away can be an element of leaving someone alone.  But it is not the point of the expression when used as an instruction.

You would use the instruction "Leave him alone" to a person who was causing some annoyance to a person. So if in school, Sally was sitting next to Joe, and annoying him by touching his hair, the teacher might say "Sally, leave Joe alone and sit at the front of the class".  But if Sally and Joe are in a room together and Sally is not annoying Joe, it would be odd to say "Leave Joe alone."

So you would not use "leave him alone" to mean just "depart from him".

On the other hand, it is possible to say, "Sally left Joe alone in his room", in a descriptive sentence, to mean that Sally departed from Joe and there was nobody else in Joe's room."